# Text To Columns VBA

Tags: excel, vba, text-to-column

I'm trying the text to column but seems I have a error. This is my Code:

```
Set rg = Range("H3:H" & lr).CurrentRegion
rg.TextToColumns _
Destination:=Range("H3"), _
DataType:=xlDelimited, _
Tab:=False, _
Semicolon:=False, _
Comma:=False, _
Space:=False, _
Other:=True, _
OtherChar:="Chr(10)"
```

[image]

Comment: Why is `"Chr(10)"` in quotes? Chr is a function. VBA sees it as a string since it's in quotes. I'm not sure if that solves the problem but it's definitely A problem.

Comment: Did you read the error message? It seems that `rg` contains more than one column because you used `CurrentRegion`.

Comment: As the error description states, this method works only on **a column at a time**. Then, please explain **in words** what you try accomplishing. The method can be used for different scopes. Do you want splitting cells content by `Chr(10)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next way. It splits the cells of column H:H by `Chr(10)`:

```
dim rg as Range
set rg=Range("H1").Entirecolumn
rg.TextToColumns destination:=rg, DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:=Chr(10)
```

or splitting only the column filled range:

```
dim rg as Range
set rg=Range("H1:H" & Range("H" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row)
rg.TextToColumns destination:=rg, DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:=Chr(10)
```

I can show you how to (theoretically) run the code for all columns of `CurrentRegion`, but such an approach will be at least strange. I mean, splitting the first range column, all the rest of the range will be overwritten by the splitting process, **everything will be ruined and nothing to be split remains**...